# How to handle huge necessary internal processes in user stories?

Tags: agile, user-story, extreme-programming

I'm looking at eXtreme Programming and its release iterations based on User Stories. But I wonder how to integrate huge internal processes into this particular mind-set.

For example, the Google crawler doesn't relate to a specific User Story, it index web pages in order to make them available to the User Story "As an Internet User I want to provide key words In order to find web sites". But the development of a Crawler is a huge set of work that isn't atomic and can't be done in a single iteration.

How can this kind of development be handled by this methodology?

Answer (score 1):

Same way you approach *any* problem: by breaking down features into stories and stories into tasks.

What you've posited as being a story is in fact not a story but an entire feature (or, in some nomenclatures, a "product" of a sense; scrum practitioners frequently use the term "epic" to describe these).

That's why you're struggling to define it and to fit into your workflow.

Comment: This answer would be much more helpful when it would provide an example how this feature could be broken down into individual stories.

Comment: I'm aware about the EPICS groups and so on, but how can I break down a huge internal process that's isn't visible from the user into multiple User Stories? (As user stories should always be related to a end user, at least it's my current understanding)

Comment: @NicoC: **Hint:** A system or automated process can also be a user.